# DIRTY_PAGE_POLL without activated Indirect Checkpoint

Tags: sql-server, wait-types, waits

Since I encounter some performance issues on my SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2370.0 (X64)) I'm dealing with enormes amounts of different wait types.

One of the top 5 wait type is "DIRTY_PAGE_POLL".

I've read this wait type will only appear when I activate the "Indirect Checkpoint" feature, which is a part of the sql server since sqlserver 2012.

None of my databases has set the Target Recovery Time.

So, why is my SQL Server polling for dirty pages without the indirect checkpoint feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [SQLSERVER-DBA.COM](http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2014/03/dirty_page_poll-and-how-to-avoid-it.html)

The background-thread is waiting to poll dirty pages even when indirect checkpoints are disabled (which is the default setting of each database)

> The interesting aspect of DIRTY_PAGE_POLL wait type , is it still appears as a wait type, even though Indirect Checkpoint is not enabled, as the background thread  is waiting to poll for dirty pages.